How to filter sites which are inside the bounding box
How to filter the sites which can be part of the bounding box only? Below are the reference objects. I would like to do this in typescript and c#
    const sites = [new L.LatLng(26.435162, 71.548647), 
                   new L.LatLng(36.435162, 71.548647), 
                   new L.LatLng(16.435162, 71.548647), 
                   new L.LatLng(26.435162, -51.548647)];

 const boundingBox =   {
        "_southWest": {
            "lat": 18.25021997706561,
            "lng": 55.92041015625001
        },
        "_northEast": {
            "lat": 29.80251790576445,
            "lng": 98.10791015625001
        }
    }

